# Web Api: Whitespace crashes the ASP.NET 4 Web Api (RC)

Tags: url, crash, uri, whitespace, asp.net-web-api

In the beta i noticed that the framework throws an exception if I call a URI with a blank.

(Yes normally the browsers replacethe blanks with '%20', but if I use fiddler or my own HTTP client I can kill the web api)

Now, the Web Api hits RC, but this bug is still present. (NullReferenceException)
Does microsoft know this bug?

StackTrace:

> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Request.IsBadPath()    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Request.TryParseRequest()    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Request.Process()    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Host.ProcessRequest(Connection conn)
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Host.ProcessRequest(Connection conn)
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Server.OnSocketAccept(Object
>   acceptedSocket)    at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object
>   state)    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   ignoreSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()    at
>   System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the stack trace of the exception?  If the top of the stack looks like this:

> WebDev.WebHost40.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Request.IsBadPath()
>   Line 435 + 0x1e bytes C#
>   WebDev.WebHost40.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Request.TryParseRequest()
>   Line 182 + 0x9
>   bytes WebDev.WebHost40.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Request.Process()
>   Line 94 + 0x9 bytes   C#
>   WebDev.WebHost40.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Host.ProcessRequest(Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Connection
>   conn) Line 75 + 0xb bytes C#

Then this is a known bug in the the Visual Studio Web Server.  Since this web server listens to localhost only, this is not a security issue and will not be fixed.

Comment: Thank you. It seems to be the same stack trace. If i use IIS the client will get a 400 Bad Request.